# Passing String From Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to pass a string from Excel userform using VBA to a Word document. In the Word document I have created a field>doc variable and called it `bookingRef`. The code is as follows:

```
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark


Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("test.docx")

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("bookingRef").Value = Me.txtRef.Text


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

objWord.Documents.Save
```

It doesn't have any errors, however when I open the document up, I have to right click and update field (I thought `objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` did this?). Also, it keeps locking the document so it cannot be opened again. Is there a way to unlock after save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is locked because you didn't close it with the [Document.Close method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.close(method)), so the document is still opened and therefore cannot be opened again.
Also avoid using `ActiveDocument` the document that was opened is set to `doc`

```
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("test.docx")
```

and can therefore be referenced with `doc.`

```
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
'Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark

Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("test.docx")

doc.variables("bookingRef").Value = Me.txtRef.Text
doc.Fields.Update
doc.Save
doc.Close
```

Also don't forget to quit your Word application after you are done.

```
objWord.Quit
```

Otherwise the instance of Word will be open until you shut down your computer.

---

The [Fields.Update method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.fields.update) should update the fields, but it might be unsuccessful because of an error. Check it for errors:

```
If doc.Fields.Update = 0 Then 
    MsgBox "Update Successful" 
Else 
    MsgBox "Field " & doc.Fields.Update & " has an error" 
End If
```

---

#### What I did (a test according comments below this answer):

*(following steps according [How to store and retrieve variables in Word documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306281/how-to-store-and-retrieve-variables-in-word-documents))*

1. Created a file `C:\Temp\test.docx`

   To use the `DocVariable` field, follow these steps: 
   On the `Insert` menu, click `Field`.

   [image]

   - In the Categories box, select `Document Automation`.
   - In the `Field names` list, select `DocVariable`.
   - In the `New Name` box, under `Field properties`, type the name of the document variable `bookingRef`.
   - Click OK.

     *Note you will see nothing in the document yet but that's ok because the variable `bookingRef` does not exist yet.*
   - Save file and close Word.
2. Run the following code in Excel

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Sub Test()
       Dim objWord As New Word.Application

       On Error GoTo CLOSE_WORD_APP 'error handling to ensure there will not be any orphaned and invisible Word application left

       Dim doc As Word.Document
       Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\test.docx")

       doc.Variables("bookingRef").Value = "This is the updated Value: " & Time
       doc.Fields.Update
       doc.Save
       doc.Close

   CLOSE_WORD_APP:
       objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=False

       If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. Open the Word document `C:\Temp\test.docx` and see that everything is updated:

   [image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice - especially regarding closing the doc and quitting word. However, I still have to go in to the doc, right click and press update field. Isnt that what doc.Fields.Update should do?

Comment: @BCLtd see my edited answer and check if the update was successfull or had errors.

Comment: It definetly is pass the variable across, but fails to update - even though I receive the message 'update succesful' - its a docvarible I am using - is that correct?

Comment: It's blank on print preview too :(

Comment: @BCLtd See my updated answer. I described what I did to test it, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: That works, I think it was something to do with Word more than the code - thanks so much